# How do I sort a wordpress category on its children categories?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

On my wordpress site I want to list art works ordered by year. My current strategy is to have a parent category "Works" and child categories "2017", 2018", and so on for every year. I can grab the parent category, but just how do I sort the works by the child categories (year)?

here's what I have now:

```
function custom_category_loop() {
// Grab all the categories from the database that have posts.
$categories = get_terms( 'category', 'orderby=name&order=ASC');

// Loop through categories
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {

    //categories Works and Exhibitions should be displayed only, and posts sorted by year
    if ($category->term_id == 4 or $category->term_id == 5) {
```

Thank you so much for help! (My head needs a refresh :-))

Fred

Comment: after you get the terms, and before the foreach, you can order them by key

Comment: something like this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/241322/82677

Comment: There is also a custom array sort function in the notes here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Comment: @Stender Your suggestion orders all categories by key. I want to sort only categories with term_id={4,5} on their children categories (year of the work). So I want to show posts ordered by year within its parent category. Hope this makes it more clear :-)

Comment: Just thinking.... Maybe there is an easier way to sort posts within a category by year? like using a custom field? Any suggestions very much welcome! Thanks